# MySql data insert after printing a page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, printing, sql-insert

I am in a project, where I have to `print a page`, then I have `insert` some data in a table. I am printing the page using JavaScript function `print()(window.print())`, but how would I insert data after printing ? I am looking for an easier & smarter way.

This is my code :

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name");
   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
   $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name");
?>
<html>
    <head>.......</head>
    <body>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
.
.
.
//some html code
<button id="printbutton" value="print" onClick="window.print();">PRINT</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#printbutton").click(
    <?php
       mysqli_query($con,"Insert into table_name .............");
       mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
              );
    });
</script>
```

This was my idea, but it's not working, as I thought. So, now what should I do ? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try ajax.? where Ajax is called on clicking print button.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better off submitting a form via ajax. For example:

```
<button id="printbutton" value="print" onClick="window.print();">PRINT</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#printbutton").click(
                  // get your variables you want to post
                  varName = varValue;
                  // issue an AJAX request with HTTP post to your server side page.
                  $.post("test.aspx", { varName: varName},
                      function(data){
                          // callack function gets executed
                          alert("Return data" + data);
                      });

                   // to prevent the default action
                   return false;
              );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function() {
var beforePrint = function() {

};
var afterPrint = function() {
  // do ajax for insert queries
};

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

beforePrint  is for actions before window.print is triggered
afterPrint is for actions after printing

**NOTE that this is not a reliable way of inserting data.. I am using this for page redirects after print**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#printbutton").click(
$.ajax({
  url: "yourPage.php",//your inserted query page url
  success: function(data){
  $("#responseArea").text(data);
}
```

});

```
          );

});
```